# Table row with white text on black background

Tags: tables, color, tabularx

I am trying to reproduce a table like those in this picture

[image: The table I want to reproduce]

So far I have

```
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| l | X | l | l | }
\hline
& Does the proposed research involve processing of genetic information or personal data (e.g. health, sexual lifestyle, ethnicity, political opinion, religious or philosophical conviction)? & &  \\
\hline
& Does the proposed research involve tracking the location or observation of people? & &  \\
\hline
& I CONFIRM THAT NONE OF THE ABOVE ISSUES APPLY TO MY PROPOSAL  & YES & \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
```

How can I get the white text on black background top row of the tables in the picture (which seems to be a three column row where the others are four columns)?. Also, is it possible to get something like the fine double line you see round the outside of the table and in fact all round the white on black top row of the table in the following higher resolution snapshot (click to enlarge):

[image]

Comment: Just note that it is (virtually) impossible to reproduce something if we can't see it. The description doesn't provide enough information as is.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.

Comment: Added a higher resolution picture that shows the lines.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include some reference to you (now visible) line specification. This is doable using the [`hhline` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/hhline). The [`colortbl` package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/colortbl/colortbl.pdf) has some examples of this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The idea is to use some of the commands provided by the `table` option of the [xcolor](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) package. The first option would be to use `\rowcolor` to specify the desired color for the whole row; however, since you need to use `\multicolumn` to override the default column specification (in order to have centered contents in some cells),the effect of `\rowcolor` will be lost, so it's better to use `\cellcolor` inside `\multicolumn` for the modified cells. The color for the text can be changed using the `\textcolor` (from the `color` package) command. These ideas can be better implemented through a new command. To get the fine double line, I used a `\fbox` (locally changing `\fboxsep`) to place a frame around the table, and a "fake" row; feel free to change the length according to your needs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newcommand\BlackCell[1]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor{black}\textcolor{white}{#1}}
}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\noindent
\setlength\fboxsep{0.6pt}\fbox{%
\begin{tabularx}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}{| l | X | l | l | }
\hline
\BlackCell{} & \BlackCell{Research on Human Embryo/Foetus} & \BlackCell{YES} & \BlackCell{Page} \\\hline\multicolumn{4}{c}{}\\[-11.5pt]\hline
& Does the proposed research involve processing of genetic information or personal data (e.g. health, sexual lifestyle, ethnicity, political opinion, religious or philosophical conviction)? & &  \\
\hline
& Does the proposed research involve tracking the location or observation of people? & &  \\
\hline
& I CONFIRM THAT NONE OF THE ABOVE ISSUES APPLY TO MY PROPOSAL  & YES & \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}%
}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The use of `\cellcolor` seems to be better, since it (from the embedded image) maintains the column rules.

Comment: @Raphael Clifford: Since you have some responses that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count. This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina, All the answers were great but I have accepted this one as it is the one I have used. I haven't managed to get quite the effect I was looking for with \hhline yet but I did add the high resolution second picture a little late.

Comment: @Raphael Clifford: see my updated answer.

Comment: Wow, that's great. One small thing, if I leave out the % after \end{tabularx} the tables stick out into the margin a few millimetres. Why is this?  Actually, I think they all stick out very (very) slightly in any case now but not that it matters visually.

Comment: @RaphaelClifford perhaps you meant the `%` after `\fbox{` ? Anyway, the reason is that without the `%` TeX sees an space and this will cause a horizontal shifting. By the way, I've changed the length for the `tabularx` to take into account the frame and prevent an overfull box.

Comment: Thanks once again! I did actually mean after \end{tabularx} as that is where I accidentally left off the % when I was trying out your solution the first time.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a mockup of what you might be after in terms of colouring the table row and text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx
\usepackage{colortbl}% http://ctan.org/pkg/colortbl
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| l | X | l | l | }
\hline
\rowcolor{black!80} & \textcolor{white}{RESEARCH ON HUMANS} & \textcolor{white}{YES} & \textcolor{white}{Page} \\ \hline
& Does the proposed research involve processing of genetic information or personal data (e.g. health, sexual lifestyle, ethnicity, political opinion, religious or philosophical conviction)? & &  \\
\hline
& Does the proposed research involve tracking the location or observation of people? & &  \\
\hline
& I CONFIRM THAT NONE OF THE ABOVE ISSUES APPLY TO MY PROPOSAL  & YES & \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You should read the [`colortbl` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/colortbl) [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/colortbl/colortbl.pdf) to see what can be done in general. The inclusion of [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) allows for shades of colours (like the 80% black I used - `black!80`).

The [`hhline` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/hhline) provides the means to draw (double) horizontal lines that have very neat intersections. Read the [`colortbl` package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/colortbl/colortbl.pdf) for some illustrations on how to incorporate colour and `\hhline` in a `tabular`(`x`) environment (section **9 More fun with `\hhline`**).

Answer (score 1):

Please provide a *full* working example next time!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\def\arraystretch{1.3}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| l | X | l | l | }\hline
\multicolumn{4}{@{}p{\dimexpr \textwidth-\tabcolsep}@{}}{\colorbox{black}{\parbox{\linewidth}{\color{white}%
 Does the proposed research involve processing of genetic information or personal data (e.g. health, sexual lifestyle, ethnicity, political opinion, religious or philosophical conviction)? }}}\\\hline
 & Does the proposed research involve tracking the location or observation of people? & &  \\
\hline
& I CONFIRM THAT NONE OF THE ABOVE ISSUES APPLY TO MY PROPOSAL  & YES & \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]